# remove_action on woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart has no effect

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce 8.5.2 with Wordpress 6.4.2. There are no other plugins installed/activated. I want to remove the 'add to cart' button in the product page and insert a custom button.

My code adds the custom button, but the 'add to cart' button remains.

```php
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_product_add_to_cart_button', 1);
//add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_product_add_to_cart_button'); //Does not work. Works upto priority 9.

function replace_product_add_to_cart_button(){
    global $product;
    if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20);
        add_action('woocommerce_single_variation', 'replace_add_to_cart_button', 20);
    }
    else {
        remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 30);
        remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30); //This does not work
        add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_add_to_cart_button'); // This works fine
    }
}
```

I have tested with several themes and none works. Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works in most themes, like WordPress default themes, WooCommerce Storefront, and many more… So the problem comes from your theme customizations, or it can be a 3rd party plugin too or some other custom code adde by you. So search or ask in your theme authors support pages. Now you should remove `remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', …` as it has no effect in here...

Comment: Thank you. Yes. It should work. But I have tried with a fresh installation of 'Twenty Twenty Four' theme with only WooCommerce plugin and the above code in the functions.php file. It is not working.

Comment: It works on WooCommerce Storefront theme (single product pages)… Also in your provided code, `replace_add_to_cart_button()` function is missing. [Screenshot of a single product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBRKG.png)

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec, I will take a look. It seems weird.

Comment: Currently I am continuing with using: `add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_false');`